# Hide value of the button

Tags: html, button

I have 3 buttons in a html page. Each contains different values, lets say answer1, answer2, answer3. I wanna pass the value of the clicked button. The thing is that i do not want to show the values on the buttons. How to hide the value of the button from the user.

This is the fiddle :

http://jsbin.com/opigut/1/edit

In this fiddle, can we change the code to show different names on the buttons namely button-1, button-2, button3 while the values are answer1, answer2, answer3.

Comment: If only there were some kind of `script`ing language that the browser could use to alter buttons and other elements that it displays....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [button](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/button.submit.html) instead of `input`

```
<button type="submit" name="choice1" value="answer1">Button 1</button>
<button type="submit" name="choice2" value="answer2">Button 2</button>
<button type="submit" name="choice3" value="answer3">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Of course, you *do* realize that this allows someone to easily cheat by viewing the source of your page, right?

Comment: If they're that smart, they deserve to pass. Who's with me?